# How can I get the latest change-set number via TFS API

Tags: c#, api, tfs

How can I get the latest change-set number via TFS API?
Could you give me an example?

Comment: Latest changeset of what? The TFS Server, Team Project, Branch or file ?

Comment: @Nockawa, lastest changeset of a team project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
TeamProjectPicker tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, true);
tpp.ShowDialog();

var tpc = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;

VersionControlServer versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var tp = versionControl.GetTeamProject("MyTeamProject");
var path = tp.ServerItem;

var q = versionControl.QueryHistory(path, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, VersionSpec.Latest, VersionSpec.Latest, Int32.MaxValue, true, true, false, false);

Changeset latest = q.Cast<Changeset>().First();

// The number of the changeset
int id = latest.ChangesetId;
```

QueryHistory is invoked with the path in the VersionControl of your TeamProject, we want the history from the latest to the latest changeset, the whole bunch of parameters left are pretty default in your case.

Comment: If you're only interested in the latest changeset, and only interested in the changeset number, I'd suggest you set `MaxCount = 1` and `IncludeFileDetails = false` to avoid some unnecessary computation?

Comment: Setting MaxCount to 1 doesn't matter as the range is 1 anyway. However you're right on the includechanges parameter, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Yep, I misread that - didn't realize you were querying from Latest to Latest.

Comment: I always get an empty enumerable :(

Comment: The code as written only works for the TeamProject with the latest checkin, all other TeamProjects return an empty enumerable (like Sam said). To fix it change the versionFrom and versionTo parameters to null and null to query all versions.