# Export TFS 2010 History to Excel or Text Document

Tags: tfs, export

How do you export history from TFS 2010 that includes the user, date and the complete comment (not truncated)?

For example, in Team Explorer: right-click team member name > show check-in history. This will bring up the user's check-in history, but the comments are truncated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to connect to the TFSWharehouse from excel, then pull the data from the source control history in a excel sheet. This is really simple and very powerful.

You'll find useful info here: http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html

**Edit:**

Using the TFS API to enumerate the changesets when you don't have access to SSAS (e.g. tfspreview.com for instance):

```
TeamProjectPicker tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, true);
tpp.ShowDialog();

var tpc = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;

VersionControlServer versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var tp = versionControl.GetTeamProject("MyTeamProject");
var path = tp.ServerItem;

var q = versionControl.QueryHistory(path, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, new ChangesetVersionSpec(1), VersionSpec.Latest, Int32.MaxValue, false, true, false, false);

foreach (Changeset cs in q)
{
    var user = cs.Owner;
    var comment = cs.Comment;
    var date = cs.CreationDate;

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("[{3}] Date: {0}, User: {1}, Comment {2}", date, user, comment, cs.ChangesetId));
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I cannot use Analysis server since we're on tfspreview.com. (afaik you cannot use Analysis server with tfspreview).

Comment: If you use tfspreview.com you don't have SSAS, that's right.
Then I'll recommend you to do a small program that does the job for you by saving a .cvs like file. To get the history of a Team Project see this answer of mine (it uses a code to connect to tfspreview), just replace the starting changeset by the first.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252742/802124

Comment: I wish I had found your previous answer earlier; I just spent the last hour figuring out the same thing with the client object model. Go ahead and post the link or same code to this answer and I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Please note that you must reference the following assemblies for the above code snippet: `microsoft.teamfoundationserver.client` and
`microsoft.teamfoundationserver.versioncontrol.client`.

Comment: I ran these two nuget installs, but I still cannot find the TeamProjectPicker class. I am developing in VS2015 against TFS 2013.

Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client -Version 15.112.1
Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.All -Version 12.0.30723.2

Comment: EDIT: I should not have run the nuget installs. I was able to add the references from the Extensions list (not the Framework list) in the Reference Manager dialog. Now it works!

Answer (score 21):

You have 3 options here:

1. Parse output from the tf.exe history command.
2. Write code against the TFS client object model.
3. Write a query directly against the TFS database.

Number 1 is probably the easiest so I'll start with that.  You can read the documentation for the tf history command [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  In order to get the comment non-truncated you will need to use the /format:detailed option.  If you want all of the history, try something like this:

tf history $/ /r /format:detailed /noprompt

If you are looking for all of the changesets for a given user, try this:

tf history $/ /r /format:detailed /user: /noprompt

That will produce a fair amount of text output that you would need to parse to be able to put it into excel.  Give that a shot and if you are interested in options 2 or 3 let me know and I can give you more details.

Comment: I'm looking for anything that will produce what I posted as an example, but without the truncated text. I'll look into using tf.exe tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, you will need to specify the /noprompt option as well.  I'll update the example commands.

Comment: Option 1 does get the complete details, including all the text untruncated. I'll probably have to write a parser to pull out the relevant information since the data does not come back on a single line, which would be ideal. I'll I'm really interested in is date, username and untruncated comments.

Comment: This worked for me, but had to add a redirecting command: `tf history $/ /r /format:detailed /user: /noprompt >c:\mydirectory\myfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [TFS Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/get%20changesets?view=vsts-rest-4.1) like this:-

```
https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?
searchCriteria.author={userName}&$top=100
```

This will generate a JSON, you can upload it to any online site like https://json-csv.com/ and get the CSV.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler rendition than the above for visualstudio.com

https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=10000&maxCommentLength=2000

You need the max comment length to stop it from truncating.
The above tool didn't work, but this one does: http://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm

Comment: Alternate URL.  "Eventually" visualstudio.com will go away.  I guess when older versions of Visual Studio are no longer supported.

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/changesets?$top=10000&maxCommentLength=2000`

Answer (score 0):

This is really not an automated export however,thought of sharing.

For VS2015 What I found easier was following(around 20 changesets)

1. Opened the branch in VS2015
2. Right Click=>View History=>All changesets Visible
3. Clicked on each changeset ==>Right Click=>Changeset Details
4. Team Explorer-Changeset Details Opens on Right.
5. Select one of the file.
6. Using **Shift and Down arrow** you can copy the entire list of files in that particular changeset.
7. Paste to an Excel Sheet(it copied the path of files with the file names)

Did above for all the changesets and got my complete list.

Comment: This would be very tedious and time-consuming for say 100 changesets.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson and that's why I mentioned in "around 20 Change-sets" in my response and I also mentioned  "This is really not an automated export however,thought of sharing".

Comment: Sorry but I downvoted this because I think it is explaining something everyone should already know, so it is just a waste of time to read it.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson when you are in middle of an issue that assumption of  "something everyone should already know"  could go away easily  and this response could help It's okay nothing major.