# Get the history of TFS for expired trial version

Tags: tfs

I installed the Basic TFS trial version and now it got expired.
It is mandatory for me to get the history of TFS.

- Where does it store the history? Does it store it in the SQL Express?
- Is there any way to get the saved history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging through the database is not trivial.  You'd have to piece the history back together and [de-deltify](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsversioncontrol/thread/fdf49109-bbb8-49f6-9966-3f0b93caec91) all the blogs.

It would be much easier just to get your TFS instance working again so that you can get the files out of it.  [TFS Express 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx) is now available, and has no such time restriction.  It's free for up to 5 users.  You may be able to upgrade your existing installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still able to do a get, you could hook up [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs). Once you execute the [git-tfs clone](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Clone), you will be able to view the history using [git](http://git-scm.com/). You can look at [this tutorial](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/15/git-tfs-where-have-you-been-all-my-life/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider trying querying the TFSWarehouse and use and automatic script to recreate history ?

**Reference**: [Export TFS 2010 History to Excel or Text Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282506/export-tfs-2010-history-to-excel-or-text-document)