# How to get length of history for all files in a folder

Tags: tfs

I'd like to know how long the TFS history is for each file in a folder. I think it would be sufficient to have the history of each file in a single text file. The command

> tf hist * /noprompt

lists all changesets of all files in a flat list like this

```
Changeset User              Date       Comment
--------- ----------------- ---------- -------------------
45788     thu               16.11.2016 Bugfix 8172
45087     thu               11.10.2016 Refactor
44621     thu               15.09.2016 Refactor
... (a lot more lines)
44179     thu               22.08.2016 Bugfix 123
43537     thu               13.07.2016 Feature X finished
43383     thu               04.07.2016 Feature Y removed
42347     thu               17.05.2016 Refactor
```

But instead I'm looking for something like

```
File: A.cpp
Changeset User              Date       Comment
--------- ----------------- ---------- -------------------
45788     thu               16.11.2016 Bugfix 8172
44179     thu               22.08.2016 Bugfix 123
43383     thu               04.07.2016 Feature Y removed
42347     thu               17.05.2016 Refactor

File: B.cpp
Changeset User              Date       Comment
--------- ----------------- ---------- -------------------
45788     thu               16.11.2016 Bugfix 8172
44621     thu               15.09.2016 Refactor
43537     thu               13.07.2016 Feature X finished
43383     thu               04.07.2016 Feature Y removed

... (a lot more tables)
```

With this info (and some good use of MS Excel) I could figure out the various history lengths.

Yet, if there's a better way to get the lengths directly from TFS, it would be fine, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Get the history for each file in a folder

This little batch script does the trick

```
@echo off
rem listAllTFSHistories.bat

for /R %%f in (*.*) do (
    echo %%f
    "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\ide\tf.exe" hist %%f /noprompt /itemmode
    echo .
)
```

Then execute

> listAllTFSHistories.bat > output.txt

and observe the results in `output.txt`. Watch out, this file easily gets big.

### Create an appropriate Excel sheet

Open a new sheet and copy contents of `output.txt` to first column `A` (because the text contains no tabs it fits all in one column). Now we need 4 helper columns `B` to `E`.

**Column `B`, the file name of the history in `A`**

The first row contains column names and in column `B` we need to initialize the first filename in row 2. So the formula(s) in `B` from row 3 on are

```
=IF(A2 =".";A3;B2)
=IF(A3 =".";A4;B2)
(etc.)
```

**Column `C`, 1 if the current row is a changeset**

Starting in row 2 you have

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(INT(LEFT(A2;7)));1;0)
=IF(ISNUMBER(INT(LEFT(A3;7)));1;0)
(etc.)
```

**Column `D`, sum up column `C` for each history**

So effectively this counts the changesets in each history

```
=IF(C2 = 0;0;D1 +C2)
=IF(C3 = 0;0;D2 +C3)
(etc.)
```

**Column `E`, the file name - again - but only for the highest changeset count**

We are close to the info we need

```
=IF(AND(D2>0;D3=0);B2;"")
=IF(AND(D3>0;D4=0);B3;"")
(etc.)
```

**The final step**

Select the last two columns `D` and `E` and copy them pressing Ctrl+C. Open a new sheet and paste *the values only*. Filter this new table so that you only see those rows that contain a non-empty string. Sort the remaining table any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

If the length in your question means the date from first changset t last changeset of a file.There are two ways could achieve what you want:

- Export your TFS history info to Excel, in excel sorting the history
  as you like.
- Using **TFS API** to achieve this: get List of files, and for each
  file get a list of Changesets, then you just need compare the first
  an last changeset.

About how to export TFS history info to Excel, you can refer this similar question in SO:  [Export TFS 2010 History to Excel or Text Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282506/export-tfs-2010-history-to-excel-or-text-document)

Abhout how to use TFS API to achieve this, you can refer this [blog](http://peterluzc.blogspot.ae/p/get-list-of-files-and-for-each-file-get.html) which contains  very detail info and sample.

Comment: With "length of history" I meant "number of entries in history". Then I'd like to have all those numbers for each file in a folder - not just for a single file.