# Get Changeset of specific project of team project of team project collection

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

using this : [How can I get the latest change-set number via TFS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249714/how-can-i-get-the-latest-change-set-number-via-tfs-api)

I can only get the OLDEST changeset of a team project and using a dialog window.

Could someone please give me an example on how to:
- set the team project collection, team project and project programmatically?
- get changeset of the project (not team project collection or team project changeset)?

E.g

```
var TPC = <NameOfTeamProjectCollection>
var TP = <NameOfTeamProject>
var P = Path
```

something like

```
TPC = @"$/House"
TP = @"$/Room"
P = @"$Bed/Sheet"
```

So at the end I would get the changeset of directory `sheet` or if left out the changeset of `bed`.

```
public static int GetChangesetId()
{
    TeamProjectPicker tpp = new TeamProjectPicker(TeamProjectPickerMode.SingleProject, true);
    tpp.ShowDialog();            

    var tpc = tpp.SelectedTeamProjectCollection;

    VersionControlServer versionControl = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();         

    var tp = versionControl.GetTeamProject(@"MyTeamProject");
    var path = tp.ServerItem;

    var q = versionControl.QueryHistory(path, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, VersionSpec.Latest, VersionSpec.Latest, Int32.MaxValue, true, true, false, false);
    Changeset latest = q.Cast<Changeset>().First();

    // The number of the changeset
    int id = latest.ChangesetId;
    return id;
}
```

I tried to change `@"MyTeamProject"` to an path but it does not work. I get an error that there is no such project.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: sorry, here you go (see OP).